# how to logical operations on bitstrings in c++?

Tags: c++, logical-operators, bit

I have to take an input in the form **10101110000** and if i take it in the form of a string,then if I want to do logical operations on that string like **OR AND NOT XOR** ,What should I do??  Any suggestions are appreciated...I am sorry if its a easy one because I am new to c++..THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

```
int main() {  
int ns,nt;
cin >> ns >> nt; //no: of students,no: of topics
vector<string> st;
for(int i=0;i<ns;i++) //taking binary strings as input
    {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    st.push_back(s);
}
string a = st[0] | st[1];
cout << a;
return 0;
}
```

This method is not working :( :(

Comment: You can use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Comment: That is bad habbit to give -1 to any question...If you don't want to answer ,pls dont answer..we are not asking questions out of fun..we are not as intelligent as you all.....so think twice befor giving -1 to any question..good bye..this is not reply to comment ..this is for general people

Comment: So you may improve your question please? _"This method is not working"_ is pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do bitwise operations, and you are sure that you will not have more than 32 bits to process (assuming a 32bit or more system), you could use `strtoul` to convert the string to an unsigned long. Because bitwise and, or and xor are *natural* on integral types. The code could become:

```
int main() {  
    int ns,nt;
    cin >> ns >> nt; //no: of students,no: of topics
    vector<unsigned long> st;
    for(int i=0;i<ns;i++) //taking binary strings as input
    {
        unsigned long val;
        char *ix;
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        if (!cin) { // control stream state (end of file...)
            cerr << "Input error" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        val = ::strtoul(s.c_str(), &ix, 2); // convert from binary to integral
        if (*ix != '\0') {     // control input validity
            cerr << "Wrong value >" << s << "<" << endl;
            i -= 1;
        }
        else st.push_back(val);
    }
    unsigned long a = st[0] | st[1];
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```